# Attach flash message to file download response in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my code, I am returning a zip file as a streamed response:

```
return response()->stream(function() use ($zip){
            $zip->finish();
        });
```

I would like to also return a status message saying "Your zip download has started" along with the response, but I can't find a way of doing it properly in Laravel.

I am using Laravel 5.2

Comment: You will have to use javascript on the client side to add an event to the download link.

Comment: The response is **either** a file stream **or** a message. It can't be both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try using the `Session facade`:**

```
//don't forget to "use Session;" at the top

return response()->stream(function() use ($zip){
    $zip->finish();
    Session::flash('message', 'Download successful');
});
```

**In your view do something like:**

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <li>{!! session('message') !!}</li>
@endif
```

Link to the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session)

Comment: This is not working in my case , i am creating and downloading the XML file in laravel.

Comment: I have try @SapneshNaik code, but it gives the empty page and file is not getting download.

Answer (score -1):

```
try this   
 return response()->stream(function() use ($zip){
                $zip->finish()->with('message','Your zip download has started');
            });


    view file add this
     @if(Session::has('message'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
            @endif
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data for more reference in laravel  5.2